# How to properly close MappedByteBuffer?

Tags: java, windows, java-9, randomaccessfile, mappedbytebuffer

This is the code I'm running:

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filePath = "D:/temp/file";
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");

        try {
            MappedByteBuffer buffer = file.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 128);

            // Do something
            buffer.putInt(4);
        } finally {
            file.close();
            System.out.println("File closed");
        }

        System.out.println("Press any key...");
        System.in.read();

        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

Before pressing a key, I'm trying to delete the file manually in FAR Manager. But FAR says that the file is locked:

```
 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
                     Cannot delete the file
                         D:\temp\file
                    Object is being opened in:
 Java(TM) Platform SE binary (PID: 5768, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javaw.exe)
```

Only after pressing a key, the application terminates and I can delete the file.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Seems to work on my end. Have you tried looking for any running java processes and shutting them down by pressing shift+escape on windows / close all instances of the file that you might have open and running it again.

Comment: Doesn't help. I can choose any arbitrary file (guaranteed to be new), e.g. D:/temp/file2441, and still face the same issue.

Comment: This is actually a Java bug (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4724038) and there does not seem to be a proper workaround. All the answers provided here so far are considered dangerous by the JDK team.

Comment: Note that only Windows shows that problem. It works fine on Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filePath = "D:/temp/file";
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");
        FileChannel chan = file.getChannel();
        try {
            MappedByteBuffer buffer = chan.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 128);

            // Do something
            buffer.putInt(4);
            buffer.force();
            Cleaner cleaner = ((sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer) buffer).cleaner();
            if (cleaner != null) {
                cleaner.clean();
            }
        } finally {
            chan.close();
            file.close();
            System.out.println("File closed");
        }

        System.out.println("Press any key...");
        System.in.read();

        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is caused by [this bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4715154): as long as the mapped buffer is not garbage collected, it will prevent the file from being deleted. I guess that the Cleaner simply does the same thing as what would happen during garbage collection...

Comment: Isn't DirectBuffer internal API? It just started showing me such error.

Answer (score 8):

@SANN3's answer doesn't work on Java 9 anymore. In Java 9 there is a new method `sun.misc.Unsafe.invokeCleaner` that can be used. Here is a working code:

```
MappedByteBuffer buffer = ...

// Java 9+ only:
Class<?> unsafeClass = Class.forName("sun.misc.Unsafe");
Field unsafeField = unsafeClass.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
Object unsafe = unsafeField.get(null);
Method invokeCleaner = unsafeClass.getMethod("invokeCleaner", ByteBuffer.class);
invokeCleaner.invoke(unsafe, buffer);
```

Comment: This indeed works, however there has to be better way than using reflection. Sounds like a Java bug/deficiency to me.

Comment: related JDK bug (closed as Will-not-fix): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6607535 basically suggested a change in JDK that would allow to open the file in shared mode so that it can be deleted even though it is open.

Comment: I played with this some more and created https://github.com/vladak/RandomAccessFileTrap that demonstrates the problem and one can see the effect of the workaround in the related Github actions run.

Comment: Also, I am in discussion with an engineer from the OpenJDK team in Oracle and he is taking a look. The problem seems to be with the mapped memory buffers not being released. That said, no promises whether this will be addressed.

Comment: The engineer hunted down the actual bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4724038 - it is actually marked as enhancement. Quoting from the bug: _With regard to the "workaround", described in the JDC comments, of (ab)using
reflection in order to invoke a mapped buffer's cleaner object: This is highly
inadvisable, to put it mildly. It is exceedingly dangerous to forcibly unmap a
mapped byte buffer that's visible to Java code. Doing so risks both the
security and stability of the system._

Comment: Also, another comment in the bug suggests that `sun.misc.Unsafe` will be going away.

Comment: @Vlad, thanks for your tests and comments. I'm okay with crashing the system when using APIs *documented as unsafe*. IMHO, the developer should be accountable for the crash, not the language team...

Comment: The actual fix will be available using the new FFM API (by calling `close()` on the `MemorySegment` returned by [the new map() method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,long,long,java.lang.foreign.MemorySession))).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java1.8 and cannot directly use sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer and Cleaner, you can try:

```
public void clean(final ByteBuffer buffer) {
    AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<Object>) () -> {
        try {
            Field field = buffer.getClass().getDeclaredField("cleaner");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object cleaner = field.get(buffer);

            Method cleanMethod = cleaner.getClass().getMethod("clean");
            cleanMethod.invoke(cleaner);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a limitation of JDK. Since the [JDK-4724038](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4724038) which tracks this problem (even though it is marked an enhancement) in JDK says that invoking the cleanup method directly is strongly advised against (also, that the `Unsafe` class might go away in some future version of JDK), the only workaround seems to be to call the GC. If using the try-with-resources for the file, that would look like this:

```java
try (RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw")) {
   MappedByteBuffer buffer = file.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 128);
   // Do something
   buffer.putInt(4);
}
System.gc();  // has to be called outside the try-with-resources block
```

I created https://github.com/vladak/RandomAccessFileTrap to demonstrate this - take a look at the detail of a build in the Github actions tab for this repository to see the actual results.