# Cannot delete temporary file after writing to it via a MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, randomaccessfile, filechannel, mappedbytebuffer

When I run this JUnit test, it fails because `file.delete()` returns `false`:

```java
@Test
public void testDeleteTempFile() throws Exception {
  File file = Files.createTempFile("_file_del_test", ".txt").toFile();
  try (RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
       FileChannel chan = f.getChannel()) {
    MappedByteBuffer buf = chan.map(
        FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 42);
    for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
      buf.put((byte) 42);
    }
  }
  Assert.assertTrue(file.delete());
}
```

Why is this the case? I thought all resources are closed after the try block
and there should be no reason that `file.delete()` fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly close MappedByteBuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238110/how-to-properly-close-mappedbytebuffer)