# Why is StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE not deleting the source file of the FileChannel?

Tags: java, filechannel, nio2, autocloseable

We have underneath method in Java which should delete the source file when its close method is called.

```
private void appendFile(Path destination, Path source) {

    try (FileChannel sourceChannel = FileChannel.open(source, StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE);
         FileChannel destinationChannel = FileChannel.open(destination, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
        destinationChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, destinationChannel.size(), sourceChannel.size());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
       // Do something with this exception
    }
}
```

Now we run a functional integration test on this and see that the source file is not deleted.

Can someone help us with this ?

Answer (score 0):

From `StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE` option documentation:

> When this option is present then the implementation **makes a best
> effort attempt to delete the file when closed** by the appropriate close
> method. If the close method is not invoked then a best effort attempt
> is made to delete the file when the Java virtual machine terminates
> (either normally, as defined by the Java Language Specification, or
> where possible, abnormally).
>
> This option is primarily intended for use
> with work files that are used solely by a single instance of the Java
> virtual machine. This option is not recommended for use when opening
> files that are open concurrently by other entities. Many of the
> details as to when and how the file is deleted are implementation
> specific and therefore not specified. In particular, an implementation
> may be unable to guarantee that it deletes the expected file when
> replaced by an attacker while the file is open. Consequently, security
> sensitive applications should take care when using this option.

So it's only the *best effort*, not 100% guarantee that it will be deleted. Maybe it's still open by some other writer?

Comment: Yes indeed, I also read that documentation, it doesn't guarantee that it's closed. Nevertheless I don't see why it doesn't close in this simple situation. No, it's not open by another writer.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue around 2015, after a user on Win7/x64 regularly found leftover files that hadn't been removed after the program terminated. After some research and trial-and-error, we found it only happened with files that had recently been memory mapped, and fixed it by avoiding memory mapping on files we wanted to delete soon/later.

`FileChannelImpl.transferFromFileChannel` memory maps the source for transfer. (Depends on your JVM — I'm basing this on OpenJDK.) While the JVM cleans up after the copy by unmapping, thus invalidating the created view, the OS may delay the actual clean-up to another point in time. Until that happens, the file has a live (but inaccessible) memory map that may prevent unlinking.

This question appears related: [How to properly close MappedByteBuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238110/how-to-properly-close-mappedbytebuffer)

For reference: jdk11/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl#transferFromFileChannel

```
private long transferFromFileChannel(FileChannelImpl src,
                                     long position, long count)
    throws IOException
{
    if (!src.readable)
        throw new NonReadableChannelException();
    synchronized (src.positionLock) {
        long pos = src.position();
        long max = Math.min(count, src.size() - pos);

        long remaining = max;
        long p = pos;
        while (remaining > 0L) {
            long size = Math.min(remaining, MAPPED_TRANSFER_SIZE);
            // ## Bug: Closing this channel will not terminate the write
            MappedByteBuffer bb = src.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, p, size);
            try {
                long n = write(bb, position);
                assert n > 0;
                p += n;
                position += n;
                remaining -= n;
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // Only throw exception if no bytes have been written
                if (remaining == max)
                    throw ioe;
                break;
            } finally {
                unmap(bb);
            }
        }
        long nwritten = max - remaining;
        src.position(pos + nwritten);
        return nwritten;
    }
}
```